# What is the correct way to reset a variable that is decremented on click?

Tags: jquery

This works but I'm assuming there is a much more efficient way to achieve this same effect.
My intention is to reset the function on the last slide so it loops.

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewtamala/JVgAC/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var i = $(".slide").length;

    $('.button').click(function() {  
        i--;

        $('.slide').eq(i).animate({"top" : "500"}, 200)
        .animate({"opacity" : "0", "top" : "000"}, 1)
        .animate({"opacity" : "1"});

            if (i === -1) {
                i++;
                i++;
                i++;
                i++;               
            }

    })    
});
```

Comment: i+=4?  Is that all you need?  Or just i = 3?

Comment: Deprecated? Did you mean decremented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another variable to hold the original length:

```
var n = $(".slide").length,
i = n;
```

At the end of your function:

```
if (i <= 0) {
    i = n;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for. On loop, I do experience an issue where the first slide repeats. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: @user2221628 Perhaps just change the condition to: `if (i <= 0) { ...`